# Show that $E(\phi(X)) = E(\phi(Y))$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X ,Y$ two random variables identically distributed and let $\phi : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a measurable function. I have shown that $\phi(X)$ and $\phi(Y)$ are identically distributed, but I don't know how to finish.

Comment: Expectation is a property of the distribution. If they have the same distribution, they have the same expectation.

Comment: Thanks, I'm kind of confused about this topic.